# Trying to run Javascript that will convert decimals to other bases using functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

**function getNumber()**:

Prompts the user until an unsigned integer is entered. Returns the unsigned integer to the calling code.

**function getBase()**:

Prompts the user until a valid base is entered. The only thing valid is “b” or “B” or “o” or “O” or “h”or “H”. Returns the base to the calling code.

**function baseConversion(number,
            newBase)**:

Returns the string version of the base 10 number converted into the newBase. For example, if number was 255 and newBase was 16, it would return “FF” since 255 is FF in base 16.

```
function getNumber(callback) {
    var num = prompt("Enter an unsigned base 10 number");
    if (num >= 0) {
        callback();
        return num;
    }
}

function getBase() {
    var base = prompt("Enter b for binary, o for octal, or h for hexadecimal");
    return base;
}

function baseConversion(num, base) {
    var num = getNumber(function() {
        var base = getBase();
    });
    // problem here is that after calling the above two methods the program stops
    //does not return to the calling function to continue excuting

    if (base == "b" || base == "B") {
        var bin = [];

        while (num > 0) {
            bin.unshift(num % 2);
            num >>= 1; // basically /= 2 without remainder if any
        }
        alert("That decimal in binary is " + bin.join(''));
        return bin;
    }


    if (base == "o" || base == "O") {
        var oct = [];
        while (num > 0) {
            oct.unshift(num % 8);
            num = ~~ (num / 8);
        }
        alert("That decimal in octal is " + oct.join(''));
        return oct;
    }


    if (base == "h" || base == "H") {
        var hex = [];
        while (num > 0) {
            x = (num % 16);
            if (x > 9) {
                if (x == 10) {
                    hex.unshift("A")
                }
                if (x == 11) {
                    hex.unshift("B")
                }
                if (x == 12) {
                    hex.unshift("C")
                }
                if (x == 13) {
                    hex.unshift("D")
                }
                if (x == 14) {
                    hex.unshift("E")
                }
                if (x == 15) {
                    hex.unshift("F")
                }
            }
            if (x <= 9) {
                hex.unshift(x)
            }
            num = Math.floor((num / 16));
        }
        alert("That decimal in hexadecimal is " + hex.join(''));
        return hex;
    }
}
```

the code stop working when i try to run it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Explain *crashes*.

Comment: Well it just stops working

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Also `var base = getBase();` is creating a local variable, it will not be accessible outside the callback function

Comment: And why do you make life so complicated with this callback just to do a prompt?

Comment: It seems that you aren't aware that `Number.prototype.toString` takes a base as a parameter to convert numbers. Consider `alert((+prompt('Enter a number')).toString(16))`.

Comment: @zzzzBov This is for an assignment and I'm not allowed to use it. Otherwise my life would be a whole lot easier

Comment: Why do you ask for input in a function that already is supposed to receive arguments *num* and *base*?

Comment: @trincot What are you suggesting?  I get rid of the callback entirely?

Comment: Certainly. Ask for input outside of the function baseConversion in two simple prompt statements; better even in a HTML form with inputs and a button to launch the function. Prompt is not really that ... ehm... professional.

Answer (score 1):

The script is overly complex with this callback system, but the main error is that you access a variable *base* which does not exist:

```
function baseConversion(num,base){
    var num = getNumber(function() {
        var base = getBase(); // this variable only exists within this function
    });
    // ... not here, where *base* is the argument passed to the function.
```

To fix:

```
function baseConversion(num,base){
    // now the parameter *base* is updated:
    var num = getNumber(function() {
        base = getBase();
    });
    // ... and still has that same value here.
```

Suggested improvements:

As the function *baseConversion* already accepts the *num* and *base* values as arguments, it is the wrong place to ask for input inside that function. Instead you should get the input before calling the function.

Instead of the callback method, ask for input in a linear fashion, or even better: create an input form where the user can choose the order of filling in and when to launch the function:

```
<input type="text" id="num"><br>
<input type="text" id="base"><br>
<button id="convert">Convert!</button>
```

This is much better than using `prompt`, but OK, if it was your assignment to `prompt`, I guess you better listen :).

#### Solution (spoiler alert)

Assuming you are not allowed to use `toString(base)` in your code, which would make it very trivial, here is what would meet the requirements:

```js
function getNumber () {
    var num, input;
    do {
        input = prompt("Enter an unsigned base 10 number");
        num = parseInt(input);
    } while (isNaN(num) || num < 0 || num+''!==input);
    return num;
}

function getBase () {
    var base;
    do {
        base = prompt("Enter b for binary, o for octal, or h for hexadecimal");
    } while ('bBoOhH'.indexOf(base) === -1);
    return base;
}

function baseConversion(num, base){
    var baseNum = base === 'b' ? 2 :
                  base === 'o' ? 8 : 16;
    var res = [], digit;
    do {
        digit = num % baseNum;
        res.unshift('0123456789ABCDEFGH'.charAt(digit));
        num = (num - digit) / baseNum;
    } while (num > 0);
    return res.join('');
}

var num = getNumber();
var base = getBase();
var result = baseConversion(num, base);
alert('result is ' + result);
```

Comment: Since `base` is defined in the parameter list you do not need the `var base` at all, just leave off the `var` keyword in the callback, or get rid of the parameter as its going to be overwriten anyway

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks for highlighting that.

Answer (score 0):

Your base variable doesn't exist outside of the callback function passed as an argument to getNumber.

[image]

You should simplify and use a while loop which checks that the prompt was valid and if it was not it simply re-prompts the user.

Something like this would work:

```
var num;
var validNum = false;
while (!validNum) {
  num = prompt('ask for number');
  // Do your validation here for num, set validNum accordingly
}
```

You could do the same thing for base.